# Find a power series representation of $\frac{8 - x}{x^2 + x + 1}.$

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

I have the next function. And I need to find his power series representation over reals $$ f(x)= \frac{8 - x}{x^2 + x + 1}$$ I can't find a way in which I can use this:
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}$$
So any help you could give will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$f(x)= \frac{8 - x}{x^2 + x + 1}=\frac{(8 - x)(1-x)}{1-x^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I must confess that I do not see why you would like to use $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}$$ Just perform the long division to get 
$$\frac{8 - x}{1+x+x^2}=8-9 x+x^2+8 x^3-9 x^4+x^5+8 x^6-9 x^7+x^8+8 x^9-9 x^{10}+x^{11}+8 x^{12}-9
   x^{13}+x^{14}+8 x^{15}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$$ in which you can notice interesting patterns.